# Add new custom ini configuration value

Tags: php, set, ini

Is it possible in php to create NEW ini configuration entries?

Something like this:?

```
ini_set('custom.ini.entry', 'my value');
```

Comment: although it was not you question, I think you want to use Global vars http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp

Comment: The .ini is a global configuration ***file*** which holds default values; `ini_set` allows you to ***override*** those at runtime. If you're *setting* values at runtime, a better option is probably to use constants in the first place.

Comment: Ok, but then, can I define custom entries in a php.ini and read these at runtime using get_ini()?